# Why does gDistance return distances that do not make sense with my data?

Tags: r

I am new to R and am working on a project for a class using R for geospatial analysis. The goal of my project is to find the distances between the points of recreation opportunities () to the the nearest national park polygon (). When I used gDistance, it returns crazy big numbers that don't makes sense with my data. Everything is within the lower 48 states. I have made sure to have all datasets in the same projection. This is the data I am using:
[NPS Boundaries](https://public-nps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/nps::nps-boundary-1/about)
[USFS Recreation Opportunities](https://data-usfs.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/usfs::recreation-opportunities-feature-layer/about)
[Census Bureau State Boundaries](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/carto-boundary-file.html)

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(spdplyr)

ops <- readOGR(dsn = "C:/Users/amand/Desktop/GISCert/Geospatial Analysis/Final/Recreation_Opportunities_(Feature_Layer)/Recreation_Opportunities_(Feature_Layer).shp")[enter image description here][1]

discamping <- ops %>%
  filter(MARKERACTI == "Dispersed Camping")

discampspts = SpatialPoints(discamping)

library(maptools)
P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs ")
npssp <- readShapePoly("C:/Users/amand/Desktop/GISCert/Geospatial Analysis/Final/NPS_-_Land_Resources_Division_Boundary_and_Tract_Data_Service/NPS_-_Land_Resources_Division_Boundary_and_Tract_Data_Service.shp", verbose=TRUE, proj4string=P4S.latlon)

distance <- apply(gDistance(spgeom1 = discampspts, spgeom2 = npssp, byid=TRUE),2,min)
```

This is a snip of the results I get, which make no sense. Why are all of the them 7,463,000+ meters?

```
      1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9      10      11      12      13      14      15      16      17      18      19      20 
7463573 7463573 7463573 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463573 7463573 7463573 7463573 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463572 7463544 7463557 7463557 
     21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31      32      33      34      35      36      37      38      39      40 
7463547 7463547 7463547 7463547 7463546 7463546 7463546 7463546 7463546 7463546 7463547 7463546 7463548 7463549 7463549 7463548 7463549 7463548 7463549 7463548 
     41      42      43      44      45      46      47      48      49      50      51      52      53      54      55      56      57      58      59      60 
7463548 7463543 7463543 7463541 7463542 7463543 7463583 7463583 7463583 7463554 7463555 7463555 7463554 7463554 7463554 7463552 7463555 7463578 7463576 7463577
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code to read the second shape file using `readOGR` and then explicitly transform it to the required spatial projection using `spTransform` because the help for the `readShapePoly` function indicates it is deprecated. The original shape file has `EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator` as its projection, so a transformation is required. The `gDistance` function requires planar coordinates, not lat long, but it's only a warning and it does work.

EDIT: added use of planar projection and use mapview to check result.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(spdplyr)
library(rgeos)
library(maptools)

P4S.latlon <- CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=NAD83 +no_defs")

#https://data-usfs.hub.arcgis.com/datasets/usfs::recreation-opportunities-feature-layer/about
ops <- readOGR(dsn = "spatialdistance/data/recreation/Recreation_Opportunities_(Feature_Layer).shp")
discamping <- ops %>% filter(MARKERACTI == "Dispersed Camping")
discampspts = SpatialPoints(discamping, proj4string = P4S.latlon)

#https://public-nps.opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/nps::nps-boundary-1/about
nps <- readOGR('spatialdistance/data/land/NPS_-_Land_Resources_Division_Boundary_and_Tract_Data_Service.shp')
npssp <- spTransform(nps, P4S.latlon)

distance <- apply(gDistance(spgeom1 = discampspts, spgeom2 = npssp, byid=TRUE),2,min)
head(distance)

# These are difficult to use 
#        1         2         3         4         5         6 
#0.5834679 0.4499780 0.5872363 0.5635809 0.9635063 1.0696972 

# Transform to use the nps projection
discampspts.proj <- spTransform(discampspts, proj4string(nps))
distance2 <- apply(gDistance(spgeom1 = discampspts.proj, spgeom2 = nps, byid=TRUE),2,min)
head(distance2) # These are in metres
#1         2         3         4         5         6 
#71733.78  54134.95  72504.21  72545.55 120861.89 129781.84 

# Plot a point and a shape to check manually that the distance is in metres
library(mapview)
p1 = discampspts.proj[203,]
p2 = nps[7,]
mapview(p1)+mapview(p2)
gDistance(p1, p2, byid = T)
#1 46179.27
```

Output from mapview showing that the point and shape seem to be about 46 km apart.
[image]

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me. Do we know what units these are in? I can't quite make sense of them, they still aren't what I am expecting, and I believe that is because the function requires planar coordinates. Should I reproject my data so that they are planar? I am not sure what projection I should use...

Comment: As best as I can judge, the distances seem to be in latitude and longitude units which is not that useful. You could use the projection of the land resources division boundary. I will edit the answer to use this and show that the distances are in metres.